# Cannot read property 'post' of undefined - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http

Below is the code snippet from my component file

```
import { Component,Injectable,Inject,OnInit, OnDestroy, EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
...
@Injectable()
export class MyComponent {
    constructor (private http: Http) { }
    saveDetails()
    {
        var response:any;
        var body       = customer_details;
        var headers    = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        var options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post("/user/add-customer-details", body, options)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
                data => { response = data},
                err => console.error(err),
                () => {
                    console.log(response);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

There is no compilation error or any other error but
when I am calling the post method it's saying `Cannot read property 'post' of undefined` so I tried `console.log(this.http);` right before the post method call, then its showing `undefined` in the browser console, I tried all the possible solutions but unable to understand why it's not working, please help...

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How do you call `saveDetails`? Why are you using `@Injectable` for component?

Comment: I have following button on my view `<button type="button" (click)="saveDetails()" class="btn btn-default">Save Details</button>` and I am just clicking the button... @yurzui

Comment: I have found the solution and posted it as answer @echonax , I am unable to accept it now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending a few hours in scratching my head and reading all the possible articles, answers, documentation and possibly everything available on the Internet, finally I found the solution.

I have just changed my constructor from

```
constructor (private http: Http) { }
```

To

```
constructor (@Inject(Http) private http:Http) { }
```

Though `@Inject` is an Experimental decorator, It's working

Thank you everyone for helping me...

Comment: Do you have emitDecoratorMetadata option in tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add **`HTTP_PROVIDERS`** to either the component providers array like this:

```
providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
```

**EDIT**

HTTP_PROVIDERS is deprecated. Import the http module instead.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule  
        ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

Comment: I already tried that, I added `import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';` and then I added `providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]` that time I got error saying `"node_modules/angular2/http/index" has no exported member 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'.`

Comment: to your module did you do

Comment: did you try import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
imports: [
HttpModule
]
})

Comment: It's already there `import { HttpModule }   from '@angular/http';` and `@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  bootstrap:  [ MyComponent ],
  providers: []
})` in my module file

Comment: actually you dont need HTTP_PROVIDERS , adding HttpModule  should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145799/discussion-between-akshay-khale-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: you sorted it out?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts friend, I have found the solution and I have posted it below...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the HttpModule to your NgModule for the dependency injection.

You can look it up here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#http-providers

> The HttpModule is necessary for making HTTP calls. [...]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts friend, I have found the solution and I have posted it below...